# Prioritize S2S VPN on AWS when using 1 VGW

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

We have the following AWS setup:

- 1 VPC
- 1 Virtual Private Gateway (VGW)
- 8 Customer Gateways (CGWs)
- 8 Site-to-Site (S2S) VPN connections

We have 4 sites, each connected to our VPC with 2 S2S VPN connections.

Currently, all routes in the routing table with destinations to on-premises CIDR blocks have the single VGW as the target.

Is there a straightforward way to prioritize one of the two S2S connections over the other for egress traffic out of the VPC?

Comment: In your route table you could try to add more specific routes for the connections you want to prioritise.

Comment: That's not really possible , 2 s2s vpns point to the same on prem, we just want one of them to be prioritized above the other due to speed specs

Comment: For example you could break a /24 into two /25s, or a /8 into two /9s. You might also be able to tweak things with a combo of BGP and static routing as per the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPNRoutingTypes.html